# Screen Share in Ionic using WebRTC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webrtc, hybrid-mobile-app

I Am Working on a Video Conferencing App using Ionic,
I am using WebRTC for it, I need to implement a feature of screen share which is easily possible in desktop based browsers, but when using the same in mobile it does not work, is there any way we can make it work.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that point i was using the agora SDK and they didn't supported ionic screen share, at the end we have to switch to react-native and write that screen sharing module by consuming the agora's native sdk.